# ASP.NET Web API message handler async

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom ASP.NET Web API message handler that for each request that comes it will save the request method and request uri to a custom database:

I'm trying to run the Save method async and I have done this so far. I just want to know if this is the right way to call Save method asynchronously? Is it correct to have `await` before Task.Run... ? Should I also add `async` on my save method: `private async void Save(`

Can somebody tell if I can use instead `TaskCompletionSource<T>()`

```
public class CustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {            
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);         

        await Task.Run(() => Save(request), cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }

    private void Save(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {            
        var method = request.Method.Method;
        var url = request.RequestUri.ToString();

        // here is saved to custom db code removed
        ............................

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post.

> I just want to know if this is the right way to call Save method asynchronously?

If this were a UI application, `await Task.Run` would be acceptable but not ideal. However, since this is an ASP.NET application, `await Task.Run` is not good at all.

On the server side, you should avoid `Task.Run` or anything else that queues work to the thread pool.

> Should I also add async on my save method?

A method should only be `async` if it uses the `await` keyword.

If your database supports asynchronous methods (e.g., [EF6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx)), then you can use those in your `Save` method, which would require it to be marked `async` (and should be returning `Task`). Then you could call it as such:

```
private async Task SaveAsync(HttpRequestMessage request);
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{            
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);         
    await SaveAsync(request);
    return response;
}
```

However, if your database does not support `async`, then you should just call it synchronously:

```
private void Save(HttpRequestMessage request);
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{            
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);         
    Save(request);
    return response;
}
```